# iphone-retina4 field required but unavailable in App config

Tags: trigger.io

Today, my app is not available due to a forge error :

```
[ERROR] Forge API call to app/083eab52d[...]12313d1adcbe/template went wrong:
        Field 'iphone-retina4' is required by field 'ipad'
```

In another app, this new launchimage `iphone-retina4` field appeared automatically in App config. But not in my main app.

I tried forgetting, and importing the app again, with no luck.

Here is my `launchimage` section :

```
"launchimage": {
        "android": "android.png", 
        "android-landscape": "android-landscape.png", 
        "ipad": "ipad.png", 
        "ipad-landscape": "ipad-landscape.png", 
        "ipad-landscape-retina": "ipad-landscape-retina.png", 
        "ipad-retina": "ipad-retina.png", 
        "iphone": "iphone.png", 
        "iphone-retina": "iphone-retina.png"
    },
```

How can I make this field appear in App config in order to add iphone 5 launchimage ?

Thanks

Comment: The config page depends on the platform version you are using. If you're using platform version v1.4.14 (or just v1.4 which is the latest) then you should see the `iphone-retina4` field. If you still can't see it, try the "clean app" action from the Forge tab for your app, otherwise you can modify `src/config.json` manually as per the docs and comment below.

Comment: Thanks for these details and the way to get this setting in the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.  Just add the following to your launchimage property settings:

```
"iphone-retina4": "iphone-retina4.png"
```

Per the [docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/launchimage.html) -

> iphone-retina4: 640x1136px - for the iPhone 5's four inch screen

Comment: Answer accepted..... but monk's comment is more precise about how to achieve this in the GUI !